# how to link against sse intrinsics when using icc on OS X

Tags: c, clang, sse, ld, icc

Not sure about **gcc**, but using **clang** I can take the address of an sse intrinsic, without much trouble, unfortunately when I try the same thing using **icc** on OS X, it fails, well to be precise the linker is unable to locate the underlying function ...

for example:

sse.h:

```
#include <immintrin.h>

static __m128i (*load)(const __m128i *) = &_mm_load_si128;
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sse.h"

int main(void) {

    char buffer[sizeof(__m128i)] __attribute__((aligned(sizeof(__m128i))));

    __m128i b = load((void *)buffer);
    printf("%i\n", _mm_extract_epi16(b, 0));
    return 0;
}
```

to be clear I do **NOT** want to use macros, for those who are curious as to why I would do this, my main goal is to create a dispatcher, preferably at compile time, depending on how aggressive the compiler optimizes, but thats another story.

```
$ gcc main.c -O0
$
$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.51) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix
$
$ icc main.c -O0
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__mm_load_si128", referenced from:
      _load in icckt7T6c.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
$ icc --version
icc (ICC) 13.0.0 20120731
Copyright (C) 1985-2012 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.
$
$ uname -a
Darwin *****-MacBook-Pro.local 13.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Sun Aug 17 19:50:11 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.115.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Comment: Write your own wrapper to the intrinsics? gcc/clang implement intrinsics as inline wrappers to their own builtins (there are a few exceptions at -O0, for the intrinsics that are only legal when one argument is a constant).

Comment: @MarcGlisse not a bad idea hopefully the compiler will be smart enough to collapse the chain to a native instruction, if one exists ...

Comment: @MarcGlisse `for the intrinsics that are only legal when one argument is a constant` I think you mean an **immediate**, since some compilers even complain about using `static const` which gets quite annoying, and yes your right, its really weird, I wish there was some consistency!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a good solution for writing code once, and then being able to compile it as either 256bit AVX or 128bit SSE.  I'm pretty sure this isn't it, though.

Notice that icc got as far as the link stage before it had a problem.  Maybe if you'd turned on optimization, it would have inlined the call and not referenced it as a symbol at all.

You absolutely need the compiler to inline the calls to your function pointers, though.  Running single SSE instructions through a function pointer is *not* going to make fast code.  (esp. if the compiler makes functions that follow the usual ABI, where all the xmm registers are caller-save (i.e. must assume that the callee clobbers them)).